# How to add fixed cost to Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, payment, development

I want to add some fixed cost like 50$ for all any shipping methods has selected when specific product in cart.

Comment: On the catalog you can add a FPT (Fixed Price Tax) which in your case would be 50$.  You can label this whatever you like as a "tax" for that particular product.  For example you might call it "Environmental Fee" or whatever the fixed cost is related to.